# delete listbox line if the index is the same as the given text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a newbie to C# and I'm having a problem deleting a `ListBox` line if the index is the same as the text I wrote it in.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<Boltok> boltok = new List<Boltok>();
    private List<CheckBox> radiogombok = new List<CheckBox>();
    private int tav = 10;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lathatosag(true);
        AdatBeolvasas();
        Megjelenit();
    }
    private void Lathatosag(bool lathato)
    {
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            item.Visible = lathato;
        }
    }
    private void AdatBeolvasas()
    {
        StreamReader olvasoCsatorna = new StreamReader("boltok.txt");
        {
            AdatBeolvasas(olvasoCsatorna);
        }
    }
    private void AdatBeolvasas(StreamReader olvasoCsatorna)
    {
        string sor;
        while (!olvasoCsatorna.EndOfStream)
        {
            sor = olvasoCsatorna.ReadLine();
            Feldolgoz(sor);
        }
    }
    private void Feldolgoz(string sor)
    {
        string[] adatok = sor.Split(';');
        boltok.Add(new Boltok(adatok[0], adatok[1], adatok[2], int.Parse(adatok[3])));
    }
    private void Megjelenit()
    {

        CheckBox checkbox;
        for (int i = 0; i < boltok.Count; i++)
        {
            checkbox = new CheckBox();
            checkbox.AutoSize = true;
            checkbox.Location = new Point(tav, i * (checkbox.Height + tav) + tav);
            checkbox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checkbox_CheckedChanged);
            checkbox.Text = boltok[i].ToString();

            pnlKozponti.Controls.Add(checkbox);
            radiogombok.Add(checkbox);
        }
    }

    private void btnVasarnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Control c in pnlKozponti.Controls)
        {
            if ((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
                listBox1.Items.Add(c.Text);
        }

    }

    private void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox rb = sender as CheckBox;
        if (rb.Checked && btnVasarnap.Enabled)
        {
            int i = radiogombok.IndexOf(rb);
            listBox1.Items.Add(boltok[i]);
        }
    }

    private void btnSzures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach( string item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            if(txtszuro.Text.IndexOf(listBox1.Text) <0)
        {
                listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
```

So the problem is at the `btn_Szures` click event.
What I want is that if the `txtszuro.Text` is the same as the index of `listBox1`. The program deletes the whole line.

Comment: What does the program *currently* do?  In what way does it fail?

Comment: **See @RobertAguilar's post** In `btnSzures_Click()` you are looping through each string in the listbox, but are not comparing those strings to the textbox.  Instead you are comparing the text of the currently selected item in the listbox to the textbox.  Try change your if statement to `if(txtszuro.Text.Equals(item))`

Comment: @Hill He would also need to loop backwards in a for loop or cast the items to a list otherwise he'd be modifying the enumerator of the foreach loop.

Comment: The program loads the text file to a panel filled with checkboxes. If i click on btnVasarnap the program puts the checkedbox lines to a listbox. What fails is that if i click on btnSzures it should delete the lines from the listbox wich index "town" is the same as the "town" i write in the txtszuro

Comment: Of course, this won't work. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx), this is what `string.IndexOf` does: `Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string in this instance.`, which is something completely different. So, have you considered changing the code to @Hill's proposal?

Comment: Yes.But it still does nothing.

Comment: Alright. So you just enter an index into the `TextBox` and then you want to delete the item in the `ListBox` at this index/position, as soon as you click that button?

Comment: Yeah. The closest thing i could do is that it deleted the line but gave back numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach`-loop is quite redundant in this case, as you're able to directly remove an item in the `ObjectCollection`. Have a look at the [ListBox.ObjectCollection.RemoveAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx)-method.
Parsing your text into an adequate integer, that should be passed as parameter for the index, can be done using `Integer.Parse`. But, you should rather consider the usage of `Integer.TryParse` as the text could be any character, but not a number.

Anyway, I would simply do this:

```
private void btnSzures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(Integer.Parse(txtszuro.Text));
}
```

This removes the item in the `ListBox` at the index specified by `txtszuro.Text`.
Another thing: You should consider the usage DataBinding as it would make your code cleaner. The data should be separated from the UI and is accessed in your code-behind and the `ListBox` just presents it.
For further information you can take a look at the [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)-class and the `ListBox.DataSource`-property.

Comment: Yeah im new to this site, so im learing how to rep some1 and such, but i think i accepted the answer

Comment: No problem, thanks. Also make sure to check, if the input is **really** a number, otherwise an exception will be thrown, if e.g. "Foo" has been typed into your TextBox.
As said, I strongly recommend `Integer.TryParse` for that one. Otherwise you could prevent the user from entering any non-number characters by handling the `KeyPress`-event and keep this solution.